# Распознавание сферических панорам

Tags: photo, панорамы

Работая над сервисом фото галереи, включая фотосферы, возникла нужда в проверке загруженного пользователем фото

Сначала пользователь загружает фотографии, а потом добавляет к ним информацию и указывает тип - обычное фото и фотосфера, после чего фотосфера должна отправиться на обработку.

Как мне кажется, чтобы не поручать администрации проверку фотографий на достоверность, можно отсеять разные "недофотосферы".

Первое, в чем стоит вопрос: стоит ли проверять фото по соотношению сторон? Посмотрев исходные панорамы нескольких сервисов обнаружил, что далеко не у всех ширина в 2 раза больше высоты

Второе: сравнивать нижние, боковые и верхние пиксели(по идее, левый столбец пикселей и правый между собой очень похожи, как и нижние пиксели между собой), но здесь же проходит любое всплошную залитое фото

Есть еще какие-то хаки?

Comment: А почему "любое всплошную залитое фото" не может быть фотопанорамой, например, светлой комнаты? )

Comment: не думаю, что эта "светлая комната" даст в результате все идентичные  пиксели, иначе какой смысл в таком фото?